# Modal Dialog cookies popup Accessibility issue

Tags: javascript, accessibility

I'm having issues to load the popup once the page is loaded.

- Modal Dialog cookies popup should appear on-load, not on click.

currently this `openDialog('dialog1', this);` won't load the function on load. Woks only on click, which is not needed.

What am I missing?

https://jsfiddle.net/davidesitua/vrf2x9kb/8/

Comment: The fiddle demo is calling that function  before it is defined. Move that call after the IIFE where it does get defined and it works

Comment: @charlietfl but I still get an error on the console?

Comment: @charlietfl If I click the error doesn't appear